# emails coming from user@www.domain.com

Tags: domain-name-system

I use google apps for my company's email but I've been having a problem lately. The thing is some people get my emails from user@www.domain.com instead of user@domain.com so when they reply to me the email doesn't get me.

I think it might be a DNS problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Is the mail being sent from www.domain.com via, e.g., a web form?

Answer (score 1):

Check your domain settings in your Google Apps control panel (Domain Settings/Domain Names) to make sure the domain is listed as domain.com and not www.domain.com

Does Google send the mail for you or do you have google forward outgoing mail through a local server?

Also, send yourself emails and look at the full headers.  Send emails to accounts outside the Google network (ie hotmail or yahoo or another free provider) and again look at the headers.

Is there a problem with the reply-to address or the from address or both?  Is there an "on behalf of" line?

If you don't have any experience reading the full headers, post it here and others can try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what edition of GoogleApps you have.  You could setup an [MX records](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=174125) for name `www.domain.com` in addition `domain.com`.  Then setup an alias to [accept mail for both domains](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53295).  That will cure the symptom, but not the real problem.

The root problem is almost certainly a badly configured web application or mail client somewhere.

DNS has little to no involement into what get placed into the From or Reply-Too headers.